# Data is not inserted in Database using stored procedure in MyBatis

Tags: java, database, stored-procedures, mybatis

I am trying to insert or update data in database using stored procedure in My batis but query was run succesfully but data is not inserted in DB. can u please help me out.

below is the calling stored procedure in mapper.xml:

```
<select id="saveExaminations" resultMap="examinationForm">
        {call SaveExaminationForms(12,31,null, 1, 100.00,0,0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1000001,0,1,123456,0,1,BCA,0000000003,2011,
        fraud,allahabad,null,Hindi,1,2,1,8)}
    </select>
```

below is the resultmap in mapper.xml

```
<resultMap id="examinationForm" type="ExaminationForm">
        <result property="id" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ID"/>
        <result property="studentId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_STUDENTID"/>
        <result property="examinationId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_EXAMINATIONID"/>
        <result property="isSubmitted" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISSUBMITTED"/>
        <result property="feeAmount" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_FEEAMOUNT"/>
        <result property="paymentTypeId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_PAYMENTTYPEID"/>
        <result property="bankId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_BANKID"/>
        <result property="isClass10CertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISCLASS10CERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isClass12CertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISCLASS12CERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isUGCertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISUGCERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isPGCertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISPGCERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isReservationCategoryCertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISRESERVATIONCATEGORYCERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isDomicileCertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISDOMICILECERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isMigrationCertAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISMIGRATIONCERTATTACHED"/>
        <result property="MigrationCertificateNo" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_MIGRATIONCERTIFICATENO"/>
        <result property="isBankChallanAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISBANKCHALLANATTACHED"/>
        <result property="isEmployerNOCAttached" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISEMPLOYERNOCATTACHED"/>
        <result property="EmployerNOCNumber" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_EMPLOYERNOCNUMBER"/>
        <result property="isAnyOtherAttachment" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_ISANYOTHERATTCHMENT"/>
        <result property="wasPunishedForUFM" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_WASPUNISHEDFORUFM"/>
        <result property="uFMExamName" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_UFMEXAMNAME"/>
        <result property="uFMRollNo" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_UFMROLLNO"/>
        <result property="uFMYear" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_UFMYEAR"/>
        <result property="uFMPunishmentDetails" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_UFMPUNISHMENTDETAILS"/>
        <result property="uFMCentreName" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_UFMCENTRENAME"/>
        <result property="otherDegreeParticulars" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_OTHERDEGREEPARTICULARS"/>
        <result property="mediumOfExamination" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_MEDIUMOFEXAMINATION"/>
        <result property="candidateCategory" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_CANDIDATECATEGORY"/>
        <result property="createdDate" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_CREATEDDATE"/>
        <result property="sessionYearId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_SESSIONYEARID"/>
        <result property="classId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_CLASSID"/>
        <result property="courseId" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_COURSEID"/>
        <result property="subjectName" column="EXAMINATIONFORM_SUBJECTNAME"/>
    </resultMap>
```

below code in my dao file

```
public void saveExaminations() throws PersistenceException{
        SqlSession session = sf.openSession();
        try{
            System.out.println("Before calling save procedure in dao file :");
            System.out.println("output of save : " + session.insert("saveExaminations"));
            System.out.println("after calling save procedure in dao file:");

        }catch(Exception e ){
            System.out.println("error in executing submit data");
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any idea about this one why this data is not inserted in db after calling saveExaminations().

Comment: _query was run succesfully but data is not inserted_ ... Any exceptions raised?

Comment: Not any single exception raised........ I am trying to see DB log.....

Comment: looks like MySQL procedure call, if your tables are transactional committing might help: session.commit()

Answer (score 1):

`SqlSession session = sf.openSession();` does not create auto commit session. 
To create one use

```
SqlSession session = sf.openSession(true);
```

Or use `session.commit()` in the end.